# AWS CodeBuild buildspec bash syntax error: bad substitution with if statement

Tags: bash, amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

**Background:**

I'm using an AWS CodeBuild buildspec.yml to iterate through directories from a GitHub repo. Before looping through the directory path `$TF_ROOT_DIR`, I'm using a bash if statement to check if the GitHub branch name `$BRANCH_NAME` is within an env variable `$LIVE_BRANCHES`. As you can see in the error screenshot below, the bash if statement outputs the error: `syntax error: bad substitution`. When I reproduce the if statement within a local bash script, the if statement works as it's supposed to.

Here's the env variables defined in the CodeBuild project:

[image: env]
Here's a relevant snippet from the buildspec.yml:

```
version: 0.2
env:
  shell: bash
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - |
        if [[ " ${LIVE_BRANCHES[*]} " == *"$BRANCH_NAME"* ]]; then
          # Iterate only through BRANCH_NAME directory
          TF_ROOT_DIR=${TF_ROOT_DIR}/*/${BRANCH_NAME}/
        else
          # Iterate through both dev and prod directories
          TF_ROOT_DIR=${TF_ROOT_DIR}/*/
        fi
      - echo $TF_ROOT_DIR
```

Here's the build log that shows the syntax error:

[image]

Here's the AWS CodeBuild project JSON to reproduce the CodeBuild project:

```
{
    "projects": [
        {
            "name": "terraform_validate_plan",
            "arn": "arn:aws:codebuild:us-west-2:xxxxx:project/terraform_validate_plan",
            "description": "Perform terraform plan and terraform validator",
            "source": {
                "type": "GITHUB",
                "location": "https://github.com/marshall7m/sparkify_end_to_end.git",
                "gitCloneDepth": 1,
                "gitSubmodulesConfig": {
                    "fetchSubmodules": false
                },
                "buildspec": "deployment/CI/dev/cfg/buildspec_terraform_validate_plan.yml",
                "reportBuildStatus": false,
                "insecureSsl": false
            },
            "secondarySources": [],
            "secondarySourceVersions": [],
            "artifacts": {
                "type": "NO_ARTIFACTS",
                "overrideArtifactName": false
            },
            "cache": {
                "type": "NO_CACHE"
            },
            "environment": {
                "type": "LINUX_CONTAINER",
                "image": "hashicorp/terraform:0.12.28",
                "computeType": "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL",
                "environmentVariables": [
                    {
                        "name": "TF_ROOT_DIR",
                        "value": "deployment",
                        "type": "PLAINTEXT"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "LIVE_BRANCHES",
                        "value": "(dev, prod)",
                        "type": "PLAINTEXT"
                    }
```

Here's the associated buildspec file content: (`buildspec_terraform_validate_plan.yml`)

```
version: 0.2
env:
  shell: bash
  parameter-store:
      AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_PARAM: TF_AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
      AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_PARAM: TF_AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_ID
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      # install/incorporate terraform validator? 
  pre_build:
    commands:
      # CodeBuild environment variables
      #   BRANCH_NAME -- GitHub branch that triggered the CodeBuild project
      #   TF_ROOT_DIR -- Directory within branch ($BRANCH_NAME) that will be iterated through for terraform planning and testing
      #   LIVE_BRANCHES -- Branches that represent a live cloud environment
      - export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=$AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID_PARAM
      - export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=$AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY_PARAM
      - bash -version || echo "${BASH_VERSION}" || bash --version
      - |
        if [[ -z "${BRANCH_NAME}" ]]; then
          # extract branch from github webhook
          BRANCH_NAME=$(echo $CODEBUILD_WEBHOOK_HEAD_REF | cut -d'/' -f 3)
        fi
      - "echo Triggered Branch: $BRANCH_NAME"
      - |
        if [[ " ${LIVE_BRANCHES[*]} " == *"$BRANCH_NAME"* ]]; then
          # Iterate only through BRANCH_NAME directory
          TF_ROOT_DIR=${TF_ROOT_DIR}/*/${BRANCH_NAME}/
        else
          # Iterate through both dev and prod directories
          TF_ROOT_DIR=${TF_ROOT_DIR}/*/
        fi
      - "echo Terraform root directory: $TF_ROOT_DIR"
  build:
    commands:
      - |
        for dir in $TF_ROOT_DIR; do
          #get list of non-hidden directories within $dir/
          service_dir_list=$(find "${dir}" -type d | grep -v '/\.')
          for sub_dir in $service_dir_list; do
            #if $sub_dir contains .tf or .tfvars files
            if (ls ${sub_dir}/*.tf) > /dev/null 2>&1 || (ls ${sub_dir}/*.tfvars) > /dev/null 2>&1; then
              cd $sub_dir 
              echo ""
              echo "*************** terraform init ******************"
              echo "******* At directory: ${sub_dir} ********"
              echo "*************************************************"
              terraform init
              echo ""
              echo "*************** terraform plan ******************"
              echo "******* At directory: ${sub_dir} ********"
              echo "*************************************************"
              terraform plan
              cd - > /dev/null 
            fi
          done 
        done
```

Given this is just a side project, all files that could be relevant to this problem are within a public repo [here](https://github.com/marshall7m/sparkify_end_to_end).

**UPDATES**

Tried adding `#!/bin/bash` shebang line but resulted in the CodeBuild error:

```
Phase context status code: COMMAND_EXECUTION_ERROR Message: Error while executing command: #!/bin/bash
```

```
version: 0.2
env:
  shell: bash
phases:
  build:
    commands:
      - |
        #!/bin/bash
        if [[ " ${LIVE_BRANCHES[*]} " == *"$BRANCH_NAME"* ]]; then
          # Iterate only through BRANCH_NAME directory
          TF_ROOT_DIR=${TF_ROOT_DIR}/*/${BRANCH_NAME}/
        else
          # Iterate through both dev and prod directories
          TF_ROOT_DIR=${TF_ROOT_DIR}/*/
        fi
      - echo $TF_ROOT_DIR
```

**Solution**

As mentioned by @Marcin, I used an AWS managed image within Codebuild (aws/codebuild/standard:4.0) and downloaded Terraform within the `install` phase.

```
phases:
  install:
    commands:
      - wget https://releases.hashicorp.com/terraform/${TERRAFORM_VERSION}/terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip -q
      - unzip terraform_${TERRAFORM_VERSION}_linux_amd64.zip && mv terraform /usr/local/bin/
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried to **reproduce** your issue, but it all works fine for me.

The only thing I've noticed is that you are using `$BRANCH_NAME` but its not defined anywhere. But even with missing `$BRANCH_NAME` the `buildspec.yml` you've posted runs fine.

#### Update using `hashicorp/terraform:0.12.28` image

[image: hashicorp/terraform:0.12.28]

Comment: I intentionally left out the code that determines $BRANCH_NAME to keep the code snippet relevant to the problem. But you can see the definition of $BRANCH_NAME from the output `echo $BRANCH_NAME` within the code build log screenshot. Thanks for the attempt, unfortunately I haven't found a solution to this weird issue.

Comment: @Marshallm Would it be possible to update the question with an example that would enable to reproduce the issue? From what I see and remember your current example works as expected and does not allow to reproduce the issue. Subsequently, it is difficult to assist.

Comment: I added the codebuild project json and full buildspec file. If needed all files are within a public repo [here](https://github.com/marshall7m/sparkify_end_to_end).

Comment: @Marshallm  I see you used custom image `hashicorp/terraform:0.12.28`, not AWS provided one. I tested with the custom image, and can confirm now that have the same issue. Though I have a bit different reason `Reason: exec: "bash": executable file not found in $PATH`.

Comment: @Marshallm My further test indicate that there is no `bash` in the `hashicorp/terraform:0.12.28`. Wouldn't it be easier to do your build the opposite way, i.e. use AWS managed image for CodeBuild, and install terraform on it?

Comment: Ah that's why, I mindlessly assumed that hashicorp/terraform:0.12.28 would have bash baked in.  I guess the `syntax error: bad substitution` error threw me off and I thought the error was strictly related to bash. I took your advice regarding the use of an AWS managed imaged instead and reflected the change in my post. Thanks @Marcin for all the help!